# Is every unitary irreducible representation an induced reperesentation?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups

I have recently read about induced representations and I have the following perhaps naive question about them.

Let $G$ be a finite or infinite (Lie) group. Can we construct *all* irreducible unitary representations of $G$ (except perhaps for 1-dimensional ones) via induction from some of its proper subgroups?

Comment: Induction from the trivial subgroup is the regular representation.

Comment: In the case of a complex semisimple Lie group, you can get the irreducible finite dimensional representations by induction from a special subgroup called a Borel subgroup (think upper triangular matrices in $GL_{n}$.) These representations are not the actual induced representations but they can be obtained from them in a nice way. The induction functor is slightly different than the standard case though because you use the universal enveloping algebra of the Lie algebra rather than the group algebra. Additionally, there is a geometric way to induce the irreducibles using cohomology.

Comment: @SiddharthVenkatesh So does that mean that the answer to my question is negative in general? If yes, are there any conditions on the Lie group which make the statement valid?

Comment: @Sam If your question is "is every irreducible representation of G exactly the induced representation from some representation of a proper subgroup H?", then I think that is never going to be the case. For example, any group has an irreducible trivial representation but the induced representation from a proper subgroup is never trivial.

Comment: In fact, it is not too hard to see why any 1-dimensional irreducible representation of $G$ cannot be induced from a proper subgroup because those must have dimension divisible by $\frac{|G|}{|H|}.$

Comment: @SiddharthVenkatesh Thanks for pointing out the issue about 1-dimensional representations. I have edited the post accordingly.

Comment: @SiddharthVenkatesh While obviously the $1$-dimensional representations cannot be induced from proper subgroups, it is possible to have all others be so (in fact from $1$-dimensional representations of subgroups, in which case such a group is called an M-group).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Thank you for your comment and also the key word. Is the M group that you have in mind the same as Iwasawa group in wikipedia? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iwasawa_group Where is a good source to read about M groups? Any famous (classes of) Lie groups which are M groups?

Comment: No, that is a different notion of M-group that I was not familiar with. In the version I mean, the M means monomial (I think the term is only used for finite groups).

Comment: As to examples (of finite groups that is), nilpotent groups are M-groups, and more generally in fact supersolvable groups are M-groups. In the other direction, all M-groups are solvable and in fact satisfy the so-called Taketa-inequality.

Comment: Ohh, and if we replace "finite Lie group" by "finite group of Lie type" and work in the defining characteristic, then something similar to the comment by @SiddharthVenkatesh holds, where we go through the algebraic groups first (and we need to assume that the characteristic is large enough).

Comment: What is a "finite Lie group"?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I suppose that was not one of the ways that sentence was supposed to be read (first option in the "or" and include the word in parantheses).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. For finite groups, the basic problem (as observed in the comments) is that a representation induced from a subgroup $H$ of a finite group $G$ has dimension divisible by $[G : H]$. In particular, if $H$ is a proper subgroup then an induced representation can't have dimension $1$, but there also exist finite groups $G$ such that the smallest index of a proper subgroup is larger than the smallest dimension of an irreducible representation which is not $1$-dimensional.

For example, take $G = A_5$. Since $A_5$ is simple, any homomorphism out of $A_5$ is either injective or trivial. In particular, the smallest $n$ such that there is a nontrivial homomorphism $A_5 \to S_n$ is $n = 5$, from which it follows that $5$ is the smallest possible index of a proper subgroup of $A_5$. But $A_5$ has irreducible representations of dimensions $3$ and $4$.

However, see [Brauer's theorem on induced characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brauer%27s_theorem_on_induced_characters).

For Lie groups the problem is much worse: depending on what you mean by induced representations, almost all nontrivial induced representations are infinite-dimensional. But there are more sophisticated things one might mean by induction that can fix this; see the [Borel-Weil theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Weil_theorem), which can be interpreted as a kind of "cohomological induction" (from a Borel subgroup).